# How to detect the presence of a Multi Stream Transport hub under Windows?

Tags: multiple-monitors, thunderbolt, mst

If a Thunderbolt device has two display outputs, it might take both DisplayPort signals off the bus or it might be using an MST hub. Is there any way to tell which one it is? Aside from, of course, trying to connect two 4k @ 60Hz monitors.

Linux has [DP branch device info on debugfs](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dri-devel/2016-September/118071.html). What about Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find the number of monitors and used lanes by using the free
[TechPowerUp GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-gpu-z/).

Under the Advanced tab, you will find the monitors and the number of lanes
taken by each one. From this data you may find the number of
DisplayPort signals taken off the bus:

[image]

Comment: Hrm, I was hoping for a utility to show the MST hub itself but this is very interesting information. So an MST hub would have Lanes (max) 2? [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lanes+max%22+cpu-z+mst) has nothing on this.  Note: there's a GPU chooser on the bottom which is cut off on this screenshot.

Comment: The DisplayPort port on the hub will be using lanes. It probably won't be using anything if nothing is connected to the port.

Comment: No, I mean, if a monitor is connected via DisplayPort, then it'll display Lanes (max) 2?

Comment: Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Main_link): "A standard DisplayPort connection has 4 lanes, though some applications of DisplayPort implement more, such as the Thunderbolt 3 interface which implements up to 8 lanes of DisplayPort". The above screenshot for my monitor uses 4.